# how can I differentiate the if the click event was triggered using the mouse or the enter key jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I have an event handler for the click event on an anchor. The event is fired both by clicking on the anchor and by the enter key when the anchor has the focus.

I wanted to know if the event was triggered by a click o by the enter key.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the enter triggering the event? Are you binding 2 events and checking keyCode, or checking keyCode then firing a `click` event separately, another handler?

Comment: Given this code I get different results: http://jsfiddle.net/TXSCZ/ IE and Firefox behave as expected. Safari always gives me a `click` and Chrome gives me results for both the `click` and pressing enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated @patrick's [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TXSCZ/1/) using a bind with `mouseup` and `keyup`. When I used `click` instead of `mouseup` my message returned that I clicked when I actually pressed enter, but just the first time.

```
 $('a').bind('mouseup keyup', function(e){
  var msg = '';
  if (e.which == 13) {
   msg = 'enter pressed';
  } else if (e.which == 1) {
   msg = 'clicked';
  }
  alert( e.which + ': ' + msg );
  return false;
 })
```

Using `e.which` you will find that 1 = left mouse button, 2 = middle and 3 = right (I believe these numbers are right). So you can include all 3 if you need to.

Comment: Cool. I didn't realize that `e.which` gave mouse button information. I guess I won't give you a hard time for not formatting your code (at first).  ;o)

Comment: @patrick - It doesn't :) jQuery normalizes it a bit: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L468 and http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L479

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("a").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
      alert('Enter!');
    }
  }).mousedown(function(){
    alert('Clicked!');
  });
});
```

Comment: Only Opera and Firefox. IE probably sucks... as usual... ;)